# Circular Range Selection

Tags: excel, vba

Is there an easy way to create a range that isn't a box, rather a circle centered on the ActiveCell? I could just define each row one at a time, but I'm hoping someone here knows a more elegant solution.

[Circle Range](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJBnC.png)

Update:

Here's the solution I settled on, thanks to JvDV's help:

```
Sub revealMap(playerLocation As Range, sightDistance As Integer)
Dim search As Range, cl As Range
Dim stcol As Integer, strow As Integer
Dim endrow As Integer: endrow = 1 + sightDistance * 2
Dim endcol As Integer: endcol = 1 + sightDistance * 2

If playerLocation.row - sightDistance < 0 Then
    strow = 1
    endrow = endrow - playerLocation.row
Else
    strow = playerLocation.row - sightDistance
End If
If playerLocation.Column - sightDistance < 0 Then
    stcol = 1
    endcol = endcol - playerLocation.col
Else
    stcol = playerLocation.Column - sightDistance
End If
Set search = ActiveSheet.Cells(strow, stcol)

For Each cl In search.Resize(endrow, endcol)
    If (Sqr((Abs(cl.row - playerLocation.row)) ^ 2 + (Abs(cl.Column - playerLocation.Column)) ^ 2) <= sightDistance) And (cl.Interior.ColorIndex = 1) Then
        Worksheets("Map Ref").Cells(cl.row, cl.Column).Copy (Worksheets("World Map").Cells(cl.row, cl.Column))
    End If
Next cl
End Sub
```

Comment: No easy way, but you could create an algorithm to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for fun. As per @BigBen, you'll need some type of logic. So for example a sample for the diamond case:

```
Sub Test()

Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range: Set rng1 = ActiveCell

For Each cl In ActiveCell.Offset(-3, -3).Resize(7, 7)
    If Abs(cl.Row - rng1.Row) + Abs(cl.Column - rng1.Column) <= 3 Then
        If Not rng2 Is Nothing Then
            Set rng2 = Union(rng2, cl)
        Else
            Set rng2 = Union(rng1, cl)
        End If
        Debug.Print rng2.Address
    End If
Next cl

rng2.Select

End Sub
```

Just like @Galimi, I did not account for edge cases.

Good luck.

Comment: This is exellent. I think i will try a more pythagorean approach, but thanks for the inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work. (This is just a mini-diamond, but you get the idea)

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

'select all the cells surrounding the current cell
Application.EnableEvents = False

strRange = Target.Offset(0, 1).Address & "," & Target.Offset(1).Address & "," & Target.Offset(0, -1).Address & "," & _
            Target.Offset(-1).Address & "," & Target.Address

Range(strRange).Select
Target.Activate
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Be sure to put that code in your ThisWorkbook object.

Comment: Did not account for edges in the above.